# How to get Token and TokenSecret for offline use in google oauth 2.0?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token, google-admin-sdk, google-api-php-client

As you know there is Token and Token secret in case of Oauth 1 for offline use ( for each time the user need not give grant access ). Similarly i need Token and Token secret for Oauth 2.

Am using PHP client library provided by Google.
Also using web applications in Google API console.

Mentioned my code below.

I need it for my Application ( for accessing Admin SDK API )

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAccessType('offline'); // default: offline
 $client->setApplicationName('SysCloud.com => For User Creation');
 $client->setClientId('107XXXXXXXXXXXsercontent.com');
 $client->setClientSecret('aeh-gQ33zXXXXXXX4K2T5K');
 $client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);
 $client->setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyBOXXXXXXXXXX7WBZ4p4'); // API key
 $client->setScopes(array(
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/',
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/',
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/',
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email',
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/'
 ));

$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { 
unset($_SESSION['token']);
die('Logged out.');
 }

 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate();
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { 
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
$client->setAccessToken($token);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { 
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
header("Location: " . $authUrl);
die;
 }
Print_r($_SESSION);

 if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
$_SESSION['accessToken'] = get_oauth2_token($_REQUEST['code']);
 }
Print_r($_SESSION);

function get_oauth2_token($code) {
$oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$clienttoken_post = array(
    "code" => $code,
    "client_id" => "1xXxxxXxxxX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret" => "aehXXXXXXXXVDiXXXXX4K2T5K",
    "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:1137/POC/UserCreation/googleapitest.php",
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
);

$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'c:/Poc/ca-bundle.crt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$authObj = json_decode($json_response);

if (isset($authObj->refresh_token)) {
    //refresh token only granted on first authorization for offline access
    //save to db for future use (db saving not included in example)
    global $refreshToken;
    $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
}
$accessToken = $authObj->access_token;
return $accessToken;
```

}

Thanks,
Gowtham

Comment: Hi., Anyone There please give give some solutions. Your solution may be help to me